# Loop over columns in SQL select

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, for-loop, select

I was looking at some [task on CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/59491429952ac97ad9000106/train/sql) to which the recommended solution was the following query:

```sql
select 
  octet_length(number1::text) as octnum1,
  octet_length(number2::text) as octnum2,
  octet_length(number3::text) as octnum3,
  octet_length(number4::text) as octnum4,
  octet_length(number5::text) as octnum5
from numbers;
```

This to me looks like something you'd write some kind of loop for if we were talking Python, C++, C# or some other programming language.

So the natural question would be if there is anything to write this as a loop in SQL.
Imagine (for whatever reason and be it purposefully bad database structure and design) there would be 95 more columns `number6` to `number100` and we want a query like

```sql
select 
  octet_length(number1::text) as octnum1,
  octet_length(number2::text) as octnum2,
  ...
  ...
  ...
  octet_length(number99::text) as octnum99
  octet_length(number100::text) as octnum100
from numbers;
```

I don't think we'd want to have a query like this with 100 lines.

So, is there a way to write this more concise, maybe with something like a loop?

Comment: No there isn't. You can of course generate the query rather than typing it all by yourself, but that's about it.

Comment: thank you, that was helpful and answered the question :)

Comment: The typical solution (without redesigning the db model) is to use Dynamic SQL to assemble the queries.

Comment: If you can live with a solution that returns the values as rows rather than columns, this is possible with some "JSON magic".